# Focusout is triggered twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a textbox and a Jquery UI dialog. When a user is done typing into the textbox and presses Enter, I want to display the dialog. In order to accomplish that I use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var helpDial = $('#helpDialog');
    var input = $('#helpSearch');

    helpDial.dialog({
        width: 800,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Templates",
        position: [165, 158]
    });

    input.focusin(function () {
        helpDial.dialog('close');
    }).focusout(function () {
        helpDial.dialog('open');
    }).on('keypress', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            input.focusout();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

<input id="helpSearch" />
<div id="helpDialog"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Fpm4/1

The problem is that when I press Enter, the `focusout` is called twice, one from the `input.focusout()` and the second time right after the `helpDial.dialog('open')` in the `focusout` event handler. This causes two background overlays to be created, and when I close the dialog, one overlay remains visible.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to handle this scenario -- 'an enter pressed in a textfield opens a jQuery dialog'. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to show the dialog box both, when the input loses focus, and the user presses enter?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that -- when the textbox looses focus or an enter is pressed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to prevent an event from firing is to unbind the event handler.  Or, depending on the situation, take differential action based on information available at the time the event fires.

The `focusout` event is triggered any time the element loses the focus.  In this case, every time the user clicks on the textbox, a `focusin` event is triggered.  As soon as the cursor leaves the textbox (which happens when the dialog box is opened), the `focusout` event is triggered.

The problem with your code is that you forcibly call the `focusout` event, and then the `focusout` event is called naturally when you open the dialog.  So, change your code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var helpDial = $('#helpDialog');
    var input = $('#helpSearch');

    helpDial.dialog({
        width: 800,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Templates",
        position: [165, 158]
    });

    input.on('focusin', function () {
        input.on("focusout", textboxFocusOut);
    }).on('keypress', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            textboxFocusOut();
        }
    });

    function textboxFocusOut() {
        input.off("focusout", textboxFocusOut);
        helpDial.dialog('open');                
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8L7EL/1/

What this code is doing is binding a function to `focusout` **within the** `focusin` **handler**.  If the user navigates away from the textbox, the `focusout` event handler will be called, which immediately unbinds the `focusout` event (to prevent binding the function multiple times).  If the user hits the enter key, then the function is called manually, which removes the `focusout` event handler before opening the dialog to prevent triggering the `focusout` event from firing automatically when the dialog opens.

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious solution might be using a variable like `enter_pressed` to inform the `focusout` function:

```
$(function () {
    var helpDial = $('#helpDialog'),
        input = $('#helpSearch'),
        enter_pressed = false;

    helpDial.dialog({
        width: 800,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Templates",
        position: [165, 158]
    });

    input.on('focusout', function () {
        if( !enter_pressed ) {
            helpDial.dialog('open');
        } else {
            enter_pressed = false;
        }
    }).on('keypress', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            enter_pressed = true;
            helpDial.dialog('open');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/7Fpm4/7/

However, I believe there's a cleaner solution. I'll try and come up with it.

**Aside**
Is the .focusin event handler really needed?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this, seeing as it's not globally scoped and works.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering if there was a way to stop an event from firing. That would be better.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7Fpm4/2/ i updated your example, just changed input.focusin(function () into input.change(function ()

Comment: That doesn't really fix the problem. Go into the input field, hit `enter`, then close the dialog. See the problem? Reload and try it with going into the field, then click off (no `enter`). I *think* that's the problem.

Comment: and if you want to clear text in input after submit, add input.val(''); before return false;

Comment: yeah, i see. i didn't saw that

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to trigger the focusout event at a place where I did not have access to the focusout event handler so I couldn't just call the function.

The way I solved it was by creating a dummy focusable input field, focusing it and then removing it. This causes the focusout event to be triggered only once.

```js
// Create a focusable dummy input element
let dummyInput = document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(dummyInput);

// Triggers focusout event
dummyInput.focus();

// Remove the dummy input element
document.body.removeChild(dummyInput);
```